# how to add multiple records in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

for example i have an array of images of a specific location lets say of new york...which i want to store in mysql... these images are coming directly from wikipedia...how can i insert these images in a loop with each image entry would get the same location name?..like this
1|Newyork|img1.jpg
2|Newyork|img2.jpg
3|Newyork|img3.jpg...so on...
what i have done so far is..

```
foreach($images as $record)//'$images' is the array of images.. 
{
$sql="INSERT INTO `search`(`id`, `name`, `image`) VALUES ('','".$data"','".$record."',} //$data is the  name of location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood well, even if I don't see your array, sth like that would be the query loop:

```
//if id is a primary key autoincrement
foreach ($images as $data => $record){
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO search (name, image) VALUES ('".$data."','".$record."') ");
}
```

but most possibly the array is of that form

```
for($i=0; $i<count($images); $i++){
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO search (name, image) VALUES ('".$images[$i]['data']."','".$images[$i]['record']."') ");
}
```

It depends of the array form.